# imputed dosage values for vcf files

Tags: vcf, snp, genotyping, imputation, chromosomes

I have one more question related to genotype file. I submitted the job in michigan imputation server.

and my imputed dosage for chr 22 file is:

> 22 16050435 22:16050435:T:C T C . PASS
> AF=0.00098;MAF=0.00098;R2=0.23769;IMPUTED GT:DS:HDS:GP
> 0|0:0.002:0.001,0.000:0.998,0.002,0.000 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0.001:0.000,0.001:0.999,0.001,0.000
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0.001:0.001,0.000:0.999,0.001,0.000
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0.001:0.001,0.000:0.999,0.001,0.000
> 0|0:0.002:0.000,0.002:0.998,0.002,0.000 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0.001:0.000,0.001:0.999,0.001,0.000 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0.002:0.000,0.002:0.998,0.002,0.000
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0.001:0.001,0.000:0.999,0.001,0.000
> 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0 0|0:0:0,0:1,0,0

Its coming like this.

wherein the test data provided in your predixcan tutorial looks like this:

> 22_16494187_C_A_b37 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Also it states that the imputed dosage should be encoded on a 0-2 scale representing the number imputed or number of the effect alleles the sample posseses. Do anyone know should I convert my vcf files to the desired input genotype file to train the model. I don't understand in my vcf files which column is representing dosage values Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [edit dosage file for various columns](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18328/edit-dosage-file-for-various-columns)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i was still working in the field of genotype imputation, a dosage was the expectation (average) of the (posterior) genotype probabilities, coded as GP in the OP's VCF. I once contributed code to bcftools to convert genotype probabilities stored in the GP field to dosages. It looks like that code may now live in a bcftools plugin called "dosage": https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/howtos/plugins.html

Comment: Yes, I used bcftools +dosage function to extract the GP field only. thank you.